# Can proxy_interfaces take a hostname?

Tags: postfix

The [manual information on Postfix's "proxy_interfaces" setting](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#proxy_interfaces) says it takes the IP address of the far end of your NAT firewall, to avoid destination loops.

What if the far end of your NAT firewall is an address provided by DHCP? The IP address might change without warning. Can I do

```
proxy_interfaces = [example.com]
```

instead?

*EDIT FOR EXTRA DETAILS:*

- My example mail server is at home.
- I have a residential ISP service, with an ISP provided router.
- The ISP side of that router is DHCP.
- The home side of that router is 192.168.0.0.
- My mail server is on the 192.168.0.0 net.
- I have no control over the DHCP address.

Comment: I can't imagine anyone setting up their router to use DHCP on the LAN side.  I suppose that must be the source of your confusion but it's hard to be sure with so little details.

Comment: That's because the DHCP is on the WAN side, as provided by my ISP.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought.  In the perspective of all your local machines, it doesn't use a dynamic IP, it has a static IP on the LAN side which you have to use.

Comment: So, I'm putting my 192.168.0.0 address in proxy_interfaces?

Comment: If it is really a proxy for your email delivery, yes.  I don't know your setup but I have a feeling you're just trying to set a machine to send emails to the Internet, so all it would need is access to the Internet.  Are you sure your ISP allows you to do outbound connections on port 25?

Comment: I want my email server to receive emails as well. I want to put my domain in my living room. :-) I don't know yet if I get port 25. If I don't, that's just a matter of changing my account with my ISP.

Comment: Not sure what types of plans your provider offers to allow email but with most providers I know it is only possible with business accounts that have a static IP.  That should be the first thing to check actually.  Don't spend a week configuring something you won't be able to use.  `telnet gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25` and see if it connects.